# Compose Tweets Picture Not Loading?

Tags: android, twitter

So I've been following this link to compose tweets from my application I'm creating: https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/compose

Now I don't get any errors in Android Studio when I test it but on my phone when I press the button everything works except it "couldn't load the picture". There is probably a simple fix with the path to the file but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the code.

```
public void onClickShareTwitter(View view) {
    File myImageFile = new File("/drawable/logo.png");
    Uri myImageUri = Uri.fromFile(myImageFile);
    TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(this)
            .text("My BMI is " + BMIMessage + ". I used the Application BMI Calculator By Dan Andersson #android")
            .image(myImageUri);

    builder.show();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
private Uri getResourceUri(Resources resources, int resourceId)
{
    return Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" +
            resources.getResourcePackageName(resourceId) + '/' +
            resources.getResourceTypeName(resourceId) + '/' +
            resources.getResourceEntryName(resourceId));
}
```

...

```
Uri myImageUri = getResourceUri(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
```